# How to run GraphQL filter query on an ARRAY field type in Hasura?

Tags: graphql, hasura, postgraphile

I'm trying to run GraphQL filter query on array field types, for example on a text ARRAY field type.

In the following example scenario:

> CREATE TABLE

```sql
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    firstName       text,
    lastName        text,    
    tags            text[]
);
```

And we can filter on text array field in one of the following ways:

> SELECT STATEMENT with CONDITION on an ARRAY type

```sql
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE tags @> ARRAY['teamplayer']::varchar[]
```

This works in PostGres and also in Postgraphile implicitly.

On Postgraphile GraphQL, we can query the above table as follows:

> Query

```
{
  allEmployees(filter: {tags: {contains: "teamplayer"}}) {
    nodes {
      firstName
      lastName
      tags
    }
  }
}
```

and the result will be:

> Response

```
  {
  "data": {
    "allEmployees": {
      "nodes": [
         {
             firstName: 'Russell'
             lastName: 'Dodds'
             tags: ['teamplayer', 'punctual']
         },
         {
             firstName: 'Emma'
             lastName: 'Samsin'
             tags: ['teamplayer']
         }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please give me some references or suggestions on how to achieve similar results on ARRAY field types in Hasura?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider editing your question—as it stands, we can't help you if you haven't provided us with any of the code you've attempted so that we can help you figure it out!

Comment: @Jeffrey,  Thanks for the feedback.  Edited as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think you couldn't use array directly in the Hasura console. You should use `jsonb` instead. It's more appropriate as you can use `_append`, `_prepend`, `_delete_key`...

But it's seems you can use `Array` with hasura. If your schema come from external service, the input for an array should be a literal. For a column of type `tags[]` the input value has to be a string like: `"{teamplayer,punctual}"`. It's how `Array` [works in postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/arrays.html).

So your mutation will be:

```
mutation {
  insert_table(objects:{
    tags: "{teamplayer,punctual}"
  }) {
    returning {
      tags
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ManUtopiK no one asked how to insert, he asked how to filter list cause thats where problems are. The solution is to use either sql queries or if you want to use graphql use postgraphile